# What is the high level software architecture of Ath11k driver?

Tags: wifi, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

Hi I am looking for a high level software architecture of ath11k driver. I am trying to write a 11ax driver from scratch, for that I want to understand the high level architecture of ath11k. ath10k is a lot different from ath11k, so I cannot use it to compare with it. If you could suggest any books related to 802.11ax device drivers, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Very ambitious goal.

Take a look here.
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/ath11k
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/kvalo/ath.git/tree